# I want my telegram bot to send messages at the exact time but when I run my code the message sends immediately and no errors pop up

Tags: apscheduler, python-3.10, py-telegram-bot-api

This is the part of the code where I tried to use scheduler

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone="Europe/Istanbul")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=\['text', \])
def get_name(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    cont = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='re.README', callback_data='yes3')
    keyboard.add(cont)
    current_user = message.chat.username
    res = engine.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(\*) FROM members WHERE username = '{current_user}'").fetchall()\[0\]\[0\]
    if res == 0:
    engine.execute(f'''INSERT INTO members (username, user_id, name, score) VALUES ('{current_user}', '{message.chat.id}', '{message.text}', '{0}');''')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 're.README')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=\['text',\])
def prom(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'gyuk')
scheduler.add_job(prom, 'date', run_date=datetime(2023, 1, 20, 14, 30))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        scheduler.start()
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
        while True:
             sleep(1)
   except:
        pass
```

I tried different suggestions from here but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the bot doesn't know the `chat.id` parameter where you want to send the message, because no message where sent to him.

If you want to schedule the sending of a message you have to iterate over the database of the people that have activated the bot correctly, and from it, you have to select the chat.id parameter so the bot knows the chat in which sending the message.

Furthermore, the scheduled function does not have to be a `handler` otherwise the bot will wait for a message to activate that function, instead of the scheduler.